# How to read multiple property files from a GitHub folder using Spring Cloud?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I have a Spring server that accesses a specific GitHub repo. The repo contains a folder and has multiple property files and all of them have different names, so I can't get them using their corresponding application and profile. Is there any way I can retrieve all of them without needing their name?
For example my  spring cloud server currently accesses the application.properties file from my github repo. If there exists  another folder and within that folder there exist multiple .properties files how do i retrieve them?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri : https://github.com/xxxxxx/cloud-config-server.git

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

FOLDER
│   ├── example1.properties
│   └── example2.properties
│   ├── example3.properties
│   └── example4.properties

Can I access all of these property files from this folder in one shot, without any specific need for their names?

Comment: "that accesses a specific GitHub repo" -- Can you elaborate on how? Using RestTemplate/WebClient to access the public URL? Using GitHub's API? Running a local git client and using `git clone`? The existing code you have would be helpful. And just an FYI, your use case sounds a little similar to what a [Spring Cloud Config server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html) offers

Comment: Yes I am using spring cloud config. I am trying to connect a server to read files from a .property file and my client then accesses it via the server. But i wish to access all the .property files from a folder.

Comment: I'm not certain (which is why I won't post this as answer), but I don't think it's possible to have zero references to the filenames without customizing how the Config server works. I would suggest looking into structuring your properties files differently, or perhaps taking advantage of [Profile Groups](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#profile-groups) if you have the ability to use Spring Boot 2.4+.